# White/blank screen after close camera in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a widget to take pictures on my app working like so:

```
final File imageFile =
        await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera).then((test) {
      print('TEST $test');
      return test;
    });
```

I can open the camera without any error and also take the picture but when I try to go back or accept the picture I've taken the app displays an white screen and the console show no errors at all.

This is failing on a real device (Xiaomi Redmi Note 8t) but it works on Android Emulator.

The only message I can see is `Lost connection to device.` when I take the camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed adding a try catch:

```
Future<Null> _pickImageFromCamera(BuildContext context, int index) async {
    File imageFile;
    try {
      imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
      .then((picture) {
        return picture; // I found this .then necessary
      });
    } catch (eror) {
      print('error taking picture ${error.toString()}');
    }
    setState(() => this._imageFile = imageFile);
  }
```

Comment: I have the same situation and your code did not worked for me

Comment: It can be related to other issue then. This definitely fixed mine. Are you trying latest version including the Flutter 2?

Comment: Yes I am using latest version including Flutter 2.0.3 version and also this is failing on a real device(Xiaomi Redmi Note 7).The only message I can see is Lost connection to device. when I take the camera. Gallery works fine

Comment: it can be totally different. Try posting a new question with your code

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for flutter 2

In Android

You need to add this to your 3 manifest (debug, main , profile)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then pick the image with a try catch, like this

```
Future getbehind() async {
    try{
      final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: (ImageSource.camera:ImageSource.gallery),)
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          if (value != null) {
            behind = File(value.path);
          } else {
            print('No image selected.');
          }
        });
      });


    }catch(e){

    }
```

Run the app in a release mode and its done!